# What order does gcc __attribute__((constructor)) run in relation to global variables in same translation unit?

Tags: c++, gcc

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023338/when-exactly-is-gcc-attribute-constructor-run) answering some of this, but at least not clearly my question.

I suspect that I should probably not access any global variables that requires code to execute (e.g. `std::string`), but how about POD variables?

```
std::string s = "hello";
const char* c = "world";
extern std::string s2; // (actually below in the same TU)
__attribute__((constructor)) void init()
{
   // safe to assume that !strcmp(c, "world");
   // not safe to assume s == "hello"?
   // even less safe to assume s2 == "foo";
}

std::string s2 = "foo";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-constructor-function-attribute) says:

> However, at present, the order in which constructors for C++ objects with static storage duration and functions decorated with attribute constructor are invoked is unspecified.

`!strcmp(c, "world")` is probably safe to assume.

---

> ```
> char* c = "world";
> ```

This is ill-formed because string literal doesn't implicitly convert to a pointer to non-const char (since C++11).

Comment: Ah, true. Sorry for the const-incorrectness. Fixing in my example.